# Checking for existence of a variable

Tags: r

I am really struggling to understand the following behaviour of R. Let's say we want to define a function `f`, which is supposed to return whether its argument exists as a variable; but we want to pass the argument without quotes. So for example to check whether variable `y` exists, we would call `f(y)`.

```
f <- function(x) {
    xchar <- deparse(substitute(x))
    exists(xchar)
}
```

So I start a brand new R session and define `f`, but no other variables. I then get

```
f(y)
# [1] FALSE
f(z)
# [1] FALSE
f(f)
# [1] TRUE
f(x)
# [1] TRUE
```

The first three calls (on `y`, `z`, `f`) give the expected result. But there is no variable named `x`

```
exists("x")
# [1] FALSE
```

EDIT I now realise that this is because of the use of `substitute`, which will create the variable `x`. But is there a way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object `x` does exist inside the function since it is the name of the parameter.

If you modify the function

```
f <- function(...) {
      xchar <- deparse(substitute(...))
      exists(xchar)
     }
```

you can see the expected output:

```
f(x)
# FALSE
```

Comment: Yeah thanks:) I realised this just after I asked the question. Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to just search the global environment

```
f <- function(x) {
    xchar <- deparse(substitute(x))
    exists(xchar,where=globalenv())
}
```

in which case you get:

```
> f(y)
[1] FALSE
> f(f)
[1] TRUE
> f(x)
[1] FALSE
> f(z)
[1] FALSE
> f(mean)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Yes, that's an other way of avoiding the error, but I would like to search through all the environments.